# T-SQL Date Difference for WeekDays only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I am trying to get the date difference in a given date excluding the week days.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT DATEADD (w, -4, GETDATE())
```

This returns *2013-05-04 19:01:53.170*, which means that it also counts weekends.

Same for

```
 SELECT DATEADD (dw, -4, GETDATE())
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you need? `Dateadd` does not return the date difference.

Comment: my bad, pretty new in Tsql. I need to get the date of the date today minus a specific number, but excluding weekdays.

Comment: Get a calendar table.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you trying to exclude Mon-Fri or Sat/Sun? In one place you say "excluding the week days" and then in another place you say "it also counts weekends". Are you trying to do an 'n-business-days' calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using these functions that return the non-weekend seconds between two dates:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateDiff_NoWeekends](
    @date1 DATETIME,
    @date2 DATETIME
)

RETURNS INT AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @retValue INT

    SET @date1 = dbo.__CorrectDate(@date1, 1)
    SET @date2 = dbo.__CorrectDate(@date2, 0)

    IF (@date1 >= @date2)
        SET @retValue = 0
    ELSE BEGIN
        DECLARE @days INT, @weekday INT
        SET @days = DATEDIFF(d, @date1, @date2)
        SET @weekday = DATEPART(dw, @date1) - 1

        SET @retValue = DATEDIFF(s, @date1, @date2) - 2 * 24 * 3600 * ((@days + @weekday) / 7) 
    END

    RETURN @retValue
END

GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[__CorrectDate](
    @date DATETIME,
    @forward INT
)

RETURNS DATETIME AS BEGIN
    IF (DATEPART(dw, @date) > 5) BEGIN

        IF (@forward = 1) BEGIN
            SET @date = @date + (8 - DATEPART(dw, @date))
            SET @date = DateAdd(Hour, (8 - DatePart(Hour, @date)), @date)
        END ELSE BEGIN
            SET @date = @date - (DATEPART(dw, @date)- 5)
            SET @date = DateAdd(Hour, (18 - DatePart(Hour, @date)), @date)
        END
        SET @date = DateAdd(Minute, -DatePart(Minute, @date), @date)
        SET @date = DateAdd(Second, -DatePart(Second, @date), @date)
    END

    RETURN @date
END
```

Here's a [**sql-fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2460/6/0) for all non-weekend days in april (22).

```
SELECT [no weekend days in april] =
    (dbo.DateDiff_NoWeekends('2013-04-01','2013-05-01')
         / 3600 / 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query below gives the difference for week days alone , Ie counts the no od days between two days and subtracts the no of weekend days ,

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
    SELECT  @StartDate = '01-July-2008',
    @EndDate = '30-July-2008' 
    ;WITH DATE (Date1)
    AS (
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', @StartDate), '19000101')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date1)
    FROM    DATE
    WHERE   Date1 < @EndDate
    )

    SELECT count(*) -
    (

    SELECT count(*)  
    --CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),d1.DATE1 ,110) as [Working Date],
    --DATENAME(weekday, d1.Date1) [Working Day] 
    from DATE d1 where (DATENAME(weekday, d1.Date1))     in ('Saturday','Sunday')

    )
    --CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),d1.DATE1 ,110) as [Working Date],
    --DATENAME(weekday, d1.Date1) [Working Day] 
    from DATE d1 where (DATENAME(weekday, d1.Date1))  not  in ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

please let me know for any clarifications

Comment: Thanks arun, though I changed "in ('Saturday','Sunday')" to "not in ('Saturday','Sunday')". Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am still missing some full testing, but this works for me too: take the difference in days and then subtract 2 days for each weekend

```
DateDiff(d, d1, d2) - 2*DateDiff(wk, d1, d2)
```

Could be put in a function as well